# Django admin template refuses to be overridden on ubuntu?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django project and I have overridden admin base_site.html to change **"Django Administration"** to **"XXX Administration."** This works fine on Windows 7. However on my Ubuntu machine, when I visit /admin, it still tells me "Django Administration!"

Now on this is the really weird part... On Ubuntu, I can run ./manage.py shell and do this:

```
import django.template.loader as loader
from django.template.context import Context
s = loader.get_template('admin/base_site.html')
print s.render(Context())
```

And it gives me:

```
....
    <div id="branding">

<h1 id="site-name">XXX administration</h1>

    </div>
....
```

Now I have no idea why the template loader is loading the right file, yet the admin page is still wants to render the wrong template, and only on Ubuntu! I feel like I'm going crazy. I tried restarting the server. On Ubuntu the server is running on gunicorn through an nginx reverse proxy.

**/project_base/templates/admin/base_site.html**

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'XXX site admin' noop %}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'XXX administration' noop %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

**/project_base/project_name/settings.py**

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')
)
```

Edit:
I think this has something to do with gunicorn / nginx. I started another instance of the server through `./manage.py runserver 7777 &` and then `curl http://localhost:7777/admin/` showed me that the correct title was being displayed. However `curl http://localhost:80/admin` is still giving me "Django Administration." Could nginx be somehow caching a previous version of the page?

Comment: Print the value of `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))` when you are using gunicorn, and make sure it is the directory you think it is.

Comment: @Alasdair In my settings.py I put `print PROJECT_PATH` and indeed my gunicorn output is giving me `/project_base/project_name` instead of just `/project_base`! Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alasdair pointed me to the problem. I assumed `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))` would always point to the absolute directory one level up from the `settings.py` file. Unfortunately, this is not the case and I'm still not sure how this magic code is supposed to work. It seems to have something to do with the directory from which you start the python interpreter.

In my case, I was starting gunicorn from `/project_base/project_name` (the directory containing settings.py). Starting gunicorn from `/project_base` fixed the problem.

Comment: If you use `__file__` instead of `__name__`, it shouldn't matter where you run the script from.